# Отправка нескольких (более 3) изображений post-запросом

Tags: swift, post

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: когда на сервер отправляю более 3 изображений post запросом, мои данные не отправляются, точнее отправляются пустые данные. А если количество изображений <=3, то запрос отправляется. Я не могу понять в чем проблема: в количестве изображений или в размере посылаемых данных. Если во втором, существует ли в *swift* лимит на размер данных, посылаемых post запросом? Есть ли у кого-то пример кода, в котором в сервер отправляется более 3 изображений?

Вот пример кода, где я отправляю данные на сервер:

```
func uploadFile( request sourceRequest: NSMutableURLRequest){
    sourceRequest.httpMethod="POST"
    let boundary = "FileUploader-boundary-\(arc4random())-\(arc4random())"
    sourceRequest.setValue( "multipart/form-data;boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let data = NSMutableData()

    for (name, value) in headers {
        sourceRequest.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: name)
    }

    // Amazon S3 (probably others) wont take parameters after files, so we put them first
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    }

    for fileUploadInfo in files {
        data.append( "\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! )
        data.append( "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fileUploadInfo.name)\"; filename=\"\(fileUploadInfo.fileName)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        data.append( "Content-Type: \(fileUploadInfo.mimeType)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        if fileUploadInfo.data != nil {
            data.append( fileUploadInfo.data! as Data )
        }
        else if fileUploadInfo.url != nil, let fileData = NSData(contentsOf: fileUploadInfo.url! as URL) {
            data.append( fileData as Data )
        }
        else { // ToDo: report error
            print("error")
        }
    }
    data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    sourceRequest.httpBody=data as Data
    let task=URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: sourceRequest as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data:Data?,response:URLResponse?,error:Error?) in
        if error==nil{
            let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
            print(responseString!)
        }else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
   //        Alamofire.upload(data as Data, with: request as URLRequest).responseString{
 //            response in
//            if response.result.error == nil {
//                print(response)
//            }else{
//                print(response.result.error!)
//            }
//        }
}
```